# OData Library serializes Edm.Single as number

Tags: json, odata, ado.net-entity-data-model

According to the specification (and the [odata.org summary](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/json-format#PrimitiveTypes)) Edm.Single (and Edm.Double) are represented 'as a JSON string' (i.e. surrounded by double quotes). However the OData Library serializes Edm.Single (I haven't verified that Edm.Double has the same behavior) as number (i.e. unquoted). Is this a problem with the library - or the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the spec (both the MS-ODATA as well as the odata.org). I verified that the product (both OData Library and WCF DS) read and write these values as un-quoted, since double can fit into JSON's number just fine. (Note that one exception of NaN and Inf which are quoted). (I'll see what we can do about fixing the spec :-))

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a problem with the odata.org summary.

If in doubt you should check out the more canonical documentation for the [format][1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541188(v=PROT.10).aspx

Comment: I mentioned that the spec also shows the values as quoted. This is from the version of the spec you referenced:

jsonSingle = quotation-mark singleLiteral quotation-mark